# Any tool to convert PDF to XLs on linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, xls

All,

Is there any tool to convert PDF to XLS on linux....

Thanks.

Comment: be more specific about your pdf

Comment: My PDf consist of few tables which i need to export it to xls

Comment: Similar to http://superuser.com/q/274573/35725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Koffice](http://www.koffice.org/). Koffice can import PDF files and save them as doc. Then you can convert DOC files to XLS... I tested this method ;)

Comment: -1 Doesn't work.  Kword and Kspread both give the error: Could not import file of type application/pdf.

Comment: @D W :  I tested this solution by my self and it works for me. BTW take a look at the screenshots [here](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/04/10/convertimport-from-pdf-and-keep-the-formatting/) and see it yourself !  ... If you have older version of Koffice take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kpdfimport/)

Answer (score 7):

try

```
pdftotext -layout input_file.pdf output.txt
```

from then you could try pasting into a spread sheet and setting the correct diameter. All  depends on the pdf in question. 
If you know some python you can also check out [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) to get the formatting you need.

Answer (score 1):

Convert pdf to txt, then convert txt to xls ;)

Maybe you wanted it the other way? xls to pdf?

Comment: No it is PDF to XLs.PDF to text .Data gets corrupted like tables and other things when converted to text and back to XLs

Answer (score 0):

If you can use java, maybe a combination of [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) and [itext](http://itextpdf.com/).